# How to kill airflow dag run that has already been marked as failed?

Tags: python, airflow

I am very new to airflow so please excuse the noobie question.

Like the title says I have an airflow dag that has been marked as failed but still gets ran by airflow scheduler. I see it in my logs. I can kill a process but the scheduler keeps respawning it in another process. How can I stop this?

Comment: Can you post the default_args for you DAG? What you're trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @raphael I mostly followed the sample for default_args `default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['abc@xyz.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}


dag = DAG('etl_1',
    default_args=default_args,    
    schedule_interval='15 11 * * *',
)`

Comment: Can you edit that into your question so it's easier to read? According to https://crontab.guru/#15_11_*_*_* your task is scheduled every day at 11:15, are you finding tasks spawning more regularly than that?

Comment: I was in the initial testing phase of my dag so I mostly ran off of manually triggered runs. One odd thing I may have done is that in my PythonOperators I used both op_args and op_kwargs which I haven't seen many examples of anywhere online.

Comment: how were you killing the process? I will also note that you have `retries: 2` which would imply Airflow would try the same task again if it were to fail.

Comment: I would mark a task for failure through the ui. I try to kill the processes by doing a `ps -ef | grep dag_ids` and then `kill pid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you kill a process you are only killing a scheduled instance of a task/dag, the scheduler will continue to create new instances based on the schedule you have provided.

For example, [this example dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.html) has `schedule_interval=None`.

You may have also set `Catchup=True` and set your `start_date` in the past, so the scheduler is backfilling all the past dates.

Comment: After reading this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html it sounds like that's what was happening. It was backfilling from my start_date